# BUILD FAILURE No plugin found for prefix 'debug'

Tags: java, maven, debugging

I am trying to run the debug. but i'm stack with this error  No plugin found for prefix 'debug' full trace:

```
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[INFO] Total time: 3.159s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 13 12:58:48 WAT 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---


[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'debug' in the current project and in the 
plugin groups
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'debug' in the current project and in the 
plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from 
the repositories [local (D:\maven2\repository), inhouse.snapshot 
(http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/content/repositories/inhouse.snapshot), 
inhouse (http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/content/repositories/inhouse), 
apache.snapshot 
(http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/proxy/repository/apache.snapshot), 
codehaus.snapshot 
(http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/proxy/repository/codehaus.snapshot), 
public (http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/proxy/repository/public), codehaus 
(http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/proxy/repository/codehaus), 
 maven2.dev.java.net 
(http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/proxy/repository/maven2.dev.java.net), 
FTRDProxy_central 
(http://maven2.rd.francetelecom.fr/proxy/repository/public)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
    please 
    read the following articles:
    [ERROR]

```
[Help1]http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/
NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Here's POM.xml :

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!-- build fail if bad dependency management -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze-dep-mgt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <failBuild>true</failBuild>
                        <ignoreDirect>false</ignoreDirect>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>5</version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-gwt-sources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <!-- used by GWT to generate javascript client 
code -->
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/exception/*.java</include>
                                    <include>**/sharedvalidator/*.java</include>
                                    <include>**/sharedconstantes/*.java</include>
                                    <include>**/shared/*.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- required on continuous integration platform -->
                <encoding>ISO-8859-15</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version><!-- 2.6 for maven : eclipse -->
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <inputEncoding>ISO-8859-15</inputEncoding>
                <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- This definition is used to generate standalone javadocs -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-15</encoding>
                <javadocVersion>1.5</javadocVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using : apache-maven-3.0.3

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using such an old Maven version?

Comment: it's not my choice we work with this version

Comment: So the answer is: No there is no good reason ;-) ....What do you mean by `debug` ? Do you want to debug the build ? (maven-eclipse-plugin is retired for a longer time...)...

Comment: yes debug the build

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but how have you called maven? `mvn package` or did you try to do `mvn debug`?